# How do I create this algorithm-like environment in which I can write full sentences?

Tags: environments, enumerate, algorithms

The textbook [An Introduction to Statistical Learning](https://hastie.su.domains/ISLR2/ISLRv2_website.pdf) uses algorithm-like environments in which full sentences are written. The environments seem to use nested enumerate environments. I would like to use something similar in a document I am writing. Here is an example:

[image]

I’ve not been able to reproduce such an environment on my own, and any help would be appreciated. Thank you for taking the time to consider my question!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Without posting a clear `MWE`, getting correct suggestion is difficult

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `algorithm` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Bayesian Additive Regression Trees}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Let $\hat{f}_1^1(x)=\hat{f}_2^1(x)=\cdots=\hat{f}_K^1(x)=\frac{1}{n K} \sum_{i=1}^n y_i$.
    \item Compute $\hat{f}^1(x)=\sum_{k=1}^K \hat{f}_k^1(x)=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n y_i$. 
    \item For $b = 2,\ldots, B$:
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item For $k = 1, 2, \ldots, K$:
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item For $i = 1, \ldots, n$, compute the current partial residual
            \[
            r_i=y_i-\sum_{k^{\prime}<k} \hat{f}_{k^{\prime}}^b\left(x_i\right)-\sum_{k^{\prime}>k} \hat{f}_{k^{\prime}}^{b-1}\left(x_i\right)
            \]
            \item Fit a new tree, $\hat{f}_k^b(x)$, to $r_i$, by randomly perturbing the $k$ th tree from the previous iteration, $\hat{f}_k^{b-1}(x)$. Perturbations that improve the fit are favored.
        \end{enumerate}
        \item Compute $\hat{f}^b(x)=\sum_{k=1}^K \hat{f}_k^b(x)$.
    \end{enumerate}
    \item Compute the mean after $L$ burn-in samples,
    \[
    \hat{f}(x)=\frac{1}{B-L} \sum_{b=L+1}^B \hat{f}^b(x)
    \]
\end{enumerate}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]